# How to find out where a Kernel32 dependency comes from

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-xp

I'm building an application to which I've just added a library (which in turn uses a number of other libraries), and for some reason it's trying to use "GetLogicalProcessorInfo" from kernel32.dll. Unfortunately, this function is newer than the Windows version that some of my users are using (some are using XP SP2, this function requires XP SP3) - so I got error reports about this.

I'm trying to figure out why this function is being referenecd, but I can't find it. I don't see it in any of the .lib files that I'm using. Or in any .cpp or .h file. Still, *something* is triggering that this function is used.

So, is there a way to find out where this is coming from? Which function or which library is using it?

I'm developing in Visual Studio 2015 with the Intel C++ compiler. There is a way to tell it to compile for Windows XP, but the minimum supported version is SP3 - before I added this library my code worked fine though. If I have to push people to move to SP3, so be it, but I would prefer not to. Many are using a pc running my software as an appliance, often not even connected to the internet, and have been running it for years (hence the old OS).

Comment: People usually use DEPENDS for this.
http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you have immunity debugger or ollydbg, you can open up your program in that. Once its loaded right click and select view which shows all the modules your program imports. Select your library and right click again and click on search->all intermodular calls and you'll see a list of functions that the module calls from external libraries. If you double click on the specific function it will take you to the location in that program which calls that kernel32 function.

Most likely you probably won't be able to get rid of it as it will be used by other parts of the library which you don't control.